# Is it possible to have Nuget bind to two different packages based on build architecture

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package

I have access to a nugget repository that has two different versions of a package, one 32bit and one 64bit.

My dev machine at work is 32 bit whereas the build server builds the solution in 64bit mode.  Currently I'm controlling the build process with ItemGroup conditions, something a bit like this:

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64' ">
```

It it possible to configure nuget to bind to one package when building in 32bit mode and the other in 64bit mode?  Or am I stuck with manually editing the *proj files?

Answer (score 0):

MSBuild is the way to go for now I'm afraid. Based on the config/platform condition, you could include a different packages.config file, or transform the contents of the packages.config file (using a placeholder or something) in a pre-build step, before restore happens.

Which makes me think you could maybe even apply this XML transformation on the packages.config file using [SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5)?